# Transclude in React using props.children

Tags: reactjs, transclusion, react-props

I have a dialog component to which header, footer and body are passed as `props.children`

my code looks like.

```
<Dialog>
<p key='header'>Header</p>
<p key='body'>body</p>
<p key='footer'><Footer</p>
</Dialog>
```

In Dialog.js

```
render() {
return(
<div className='modal'>
{this.props.children.find(obj => obj.key==='header')}
{this.props.children.find(obj => obj.key==='body')}
{this.props.children.find(obj => obj.key==='footer')}
</div>
)
}
```

Is this the best way to pass children with name(key)?

Am I misusing the 'key'?

Answer (score 1):

`Key` is supposed to be a `reserved keyword` in React. If at all you wish to use an id from the element, pass it as `id` and not `key` Also it seems pretty useless to me that you are trying to find the relevant children for each and every one of the child keys. You would simply write

```
render() {
   return(
      <div className='modal'>
         {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I may need to give different styles or classNames for different children.

Comment: Most often you would pass those styles or props or classnames directly from the parent where you defined them

Comment: Well, in that case you might be just killing my purpose of having a wrapper. I may wrap the `{this.props.children.find(obj => obj.key==='footer')}` in a div and keep some class name biz logic in the react component.

Comment: @SreeraghAR you would end up slowing the performance because of unnecessary calculation with .find as you app grows. The simples and best way is to actually style them in parent

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass custom props to children depending on them props :

```
render() {
   return(
      <div className='modal'>
         {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
            switch (child.key) {
               case: 'header':
                  return React.cloneElement(child, {
                     className: 'customClass' 
                  });
           ... // do every case in switch
         })}
      </div>
    )
}
```

You can do this to pass the key to className :

```
return (
      <div>
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
          return React.cloneElement(child, {
            className: child.key
          });
        })}
      </div>
    );
```

If possible you should handle this directly when you declare these children in your code for better performance :

```
<Dialog>
    <p key='header' className='dialog-header' >Header</p>
    <p key='body' className='dialog-body'>body</p>
    <p key='footer' className='dialog-footer'><Footer</p>
</Dialog>
```

To simply render them with `{this.props.children}`